# How to format Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this excursie

> Write the query, showing prices of all products in one column
>   with the following condition: "The price [Product Name] is
>   [Price] lv.

The table looks like this

[image: http://i52.tinypic.com/2s60bkn.png]

Comment: You need to also specify the name of the table, and what price do you want the Dostawana or Prodajna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, what you are looking for is the concatenation operator ||

You can produce the product name and price in one column like this

```
SELECT 'The price of [' || PRODNAME || '] is [' || PRODAJNACENA || '] lv' 
FROM your_table_name;
```